# Trying to download file from FileCabinet in NetSuite using C# program

Tags: c#, netsuite

I need to download JPG file from `FileCabinet` in `NetSuite`. For that I know the file name, so I searched file and assigned to `FileObject`. I got the object right, but got `NULL` content. I am providing here some code. Can anybody point out the error or any missing step here? Thank you.

```
var result = _service.search(flSearch);
if (result.totalRecords > 0)
{
    recordList = result.recordList;
    Record[] records = new Record[recordList.Length];
    for (int j = 0; j < recordList.Length; j++)
    {
        if (recordList[j] is File)
        {
            File itemImage = (File)(recordList[j]);            
            byte[] data;
            data = new Byte[(int)itemImage.fileSize];
            data = itemImage.content;  //Here getting NULL value
            FileStream inFile;
            using (inFile = new FileStream("newImage.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                inFile.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: before you do enter the for loop are you sure that you are getting a length > 0 why not add an If Statement to check the length first.. before you enter the for loop .. also when you debug this code..are you getting any errors..?

Comment: Yes I am getting the length in IF statement, it is not file length.But even I am getting file size as 24567 but not getting content of the file.

Comment: ItemImage.content is a string in base64.

Answer (score 2):

itemImage is just a string - base64.

take that string and do a base64 decode and save that to your local file.

Comment: In my case, itemImage is an object rather than a string.

Comment: In the case above, itemImage null.

Comment: file.content is the contents of the file. base64 decode that and save it to file system.

Answer (score 1):

If the search is based on the internal id of the file you want to search, then the following code may help

```
        var service = LoginNetSuite();
        Tuple<string, string> fileContent = null;

        FileSearch fileSearch = new FileSearch();
        FileSearchBasic fileSearchBasic = new FileSearchBasic();

        // Specify the folder in which the search is to be done.
        SearchMultiSelectField folderFilter = new SearchMultiSelectField();
        folderFilter.@operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
        folderFilter.operatorSpecified = true;
        RecordRef[] folder = new RecordRef[1];
        folder[0] = new RecordRef();
        folder[0].internalId = "78990"; // 78990 => Internal id of the folder.
        folderFilter.searchValue = folder;
        fileSearchBasic.folder = folderFilter;

        // Specify the file internal id.
        SearchMultiSelectField fileFilter = new SearchMultiSelectField();
        fileFilter.@operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
        fileFilter.operatorSpecified = true;
        RecordRef[] rec = new RecordRef[1];
        rec[0] = new RecordRef();
        rec[0].internalId = "345656"; // 345656 => Internal id of the file.
        fileFilter.searchValue = rec;

        fileSearchBasic.internalId = fileFilter;
        fileSearch.basic = fileSearchBasic;

        var result = service.search(fileSearch);
        var recordList = (Record[])result.recordList;
        if (recordList != null && recordList.Length != 0)
        {
            var file = (File)result.recordList.First();
            fileContent = new Tuple<string, string>(file.url, file.name);
        }
```

In this code the folder internal id and the file internal id is given as the search parameters. So the file search will be done in the specified file cabinet with specified file id.
The response from netsuite will consist of the internal id, file name, url, folder name etc. The file can be downloaded from the url location.

Comment: I am able to get the File Content with file URL at this point fileContent = new Tuple<string, string>(file.url, file.name); now how do I save the file to the local drive.